# Typescript error ts(2322) in reducer return

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I want to sort my state and delete exact name, i do it with map&filter, they should return the same state, but with a few changes. But TypeScript threw an error `2322`

I use **TS+Redux** Toolkit

This is the reducer

```
removeName(state, action: PayloadAction<IAction>) {
  return state.teams.map((i) =>
    i.leadName === action.payload.leadName
      ? i.employees.filter((n) => n.name != action.payload.name)
      : i
  );
}
```

And this is the `InitialState` interfaces and others

```
interface InitialTeamState {
  teams: TeamsState[];
}

const initialState: InitialTeamState = {
  teams: []
};

interface IEmployee {
  name?: string;
  birthDate?: number;
  citizenship?: string;
  adress?: string;
  teamLead?: string;
  position?: string;
  phoneNumber?: number | string;
  mail?: string;
  workMail?: string;
  whenHired?: string;
  registration?: number | string;
}

interface TeamsState {
  id: number;
  leadName: string;
  employees: IEmployee[];
}

interface IAction {
  name?: string;
  leadName?: string;
};
```

And the error : [image]

Comment: Do you use `createSlice`? Show the code

Answer (score 0):

Before your state has the shape `state = { teams }`, after it has the shape `state = teams` - it is totally correct that TS is telling you that this is wrong.

Maybe you wanted to do

```js
removeName(state, action: PayloadAction<IAction>) {
  state.teams = state.teams.map((i) =>
    i.leadName === action.payload.leadName
      ? i.employees.filter((n) => n.name != action.payload.name)
      : i
  );
}
```

instead?

Comment: removeName(state, action: PayloadAction<IAction>) {
      state.teams = state.teams.map(team =>
 team.leadName === action.payload.leadName ?
{...team, employees : team.employees.filter(employee => 
employee.name !== action.payload.name)} : team)
    },


Found my mistake) 
Thanks